# Choose contact name manually?

Tags: contacts, facebook

In my contact list, I entered a number of "household" contacts combined together.  For example, "Bob & Sally Smith", with the corresponding e-mail addresses, phone numbers, etc.  The problem is that, if the e-mail address is also associated with a Facebook contact, it overrides my preferred naming system and shows the name of the Facebook contact.  For example, if the e-mail address were Bob's in my example, it would show "Bob Smith" instead of the combined name.

Is there a way to force it to use the name *I* prefer it to use?

Note that this *may* be specific to my phone - Motorola Droid.  A friend of mine has the Droid X and I might see if his does the same thing...

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue? Just recently purchased a Droid 2 Global from Verizon and would love to find a solution to this as well.

Answer (score 2):

As always, it's a different Android device (but same Android version, however) so YMMV...

The Samsung Vibrant (aka Galaxy S) has a *Mark as default* menu option when you open a contact.  If you have more than one linked contact (with different names), it allows you to select which name appears in the contact list.

Comment: Yeah, mine doesn't have this...  :(  Oh, well.  That would definitely be my preferred way to do it, so I'll accept your answer.  Google contacts vs. phone contacts are really a mess...

Comment: @Galactic: Something else that I've noticed is that my phone's _Contacts_ application will display the most recently added of any linked contacts by default.  Might be worth checking if your phone behaves the same.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it appears to do but it links the Facebook contact automatically based on the e-mail address so I can't control it very easily...

Comment: Sorry, didn't explain myself well... I meant to backup the "Bob & Sally" contact to a .vcf, delete "Bob & Sally" and "Facebook Bob", then re-import "Facebook Bob" and "Bob & Sally" in that order.  Assuming the contact-linking is symmetric, you should see "Bob & Sally" in the Contact list.

Answer (score 1):

As someone replied [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/how-can-i-specify-a-default-contact-for-merged-contacts), if you edit the account info (in this case the name) you want to be displayed on the actual phone and save it, it will change the displayed name to the updated one. It worked on my xperia x10 mini.

Answer (score 0):

i use galaxy 5, my phone can choose which contact to appear, i just switch off other contact other than the phone number...problem solved. I used swype before to key in words but it will affect the contact in the messaging, if you encounter this problem, just choose standard qwerty keyboard or number pad.

Answer (score 0):

On **HTC Desire** (*Android 2.2*) you can just click on the **Link/contact source** icon in the top right when you are viewing a contact and in appeared screen there will be a name drop-down where you can choose the display name from all linked contacts (like phone and Facebook contacts in your situation).