# How can I specify a default contact for merged contacts?

Tags: contacts, sync

I have some contacts on my phone that appear in all or some of:

- my phone
- my google contacts
- skype
- facebook

Thankfully, Android allows me to link that contacts, so that I have only one entry in my phonebook with access to all the different sources.  However, the names aren't always identical.  For instance:

- in some cases the name is in English, in others in Hebrew
- some have the full name, others only the first name

Is there any way to select which of these is the default display name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choose contact name manually?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/726/choose-contact-name-manually)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit the contact you want to be the default.
Then press the menu button and join the additional contacts. 
This will keep the display name as the original contact you were editing.

Answer (score 1):

If contacts are already merged, open the contact, press menu/More button, and choose `Mark as default`. This will open a picklist of the linked contacts. The one you pick will set the contact's display name.

Comment: I don't see that on my phone?  Is this true for stock android or only for some variants?

Comment: Which version did you use? Tested it with Samsung stock 4.1.2. Possible it is Samsung only?

Comment: I am using stock on a Nexus.