# Using another name on the e-mail address of a contact

Tags: contacts

Is it possible to use another name for e-mail addresses of a specific contact? E.g. I prefer my phone contacts to have their names in greek, but when I send them e-mails I would like to have their names in english in case a foreign recipient is also included in the e-mail.

Comment: Possibly related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/726/choose-contact-name-manually?rq=1

Comment: Also possibly related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/how-can-i-specify-a-default-contact-for-merged-contacts?rq=1